# Change CSS Class through Javascript or php

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change a css class attributes on a specific page, but I can't get it to work

My code is this.

```
if ( is_page(877) ) { 
    //change CSS Class

} else if ( is_page(970) ) {
    //change CSS Class
} else {
    // Same CSS
}
```

I have tried all these insde the IFs but nothing.

```
document.getElementById('header-aside').className = 'header-two-aside2';

document.getElementById('header-aside').classList.add('header-two-aside2');

$('#header-aside').removeClass('header-two-aside');

$('#header-aside').addClass('header-two-aside');
```

What Can I do?

Comment: what does is_page() return???

Comment: And you don't show your HTML.

Comment: PHP is a serverside programming language. You cant alter CSS declarations unless you serve/prepare the stylesheet via PHP.

Comment: Do the if statements even get executed? Try adding some `alert('...')`s to check if they do.

Comment: What behavior do you get? A JavaScript exception? Unchanged class attributes?

Comment: May be you need quotes around params is_page("877") ???

Comment: Try to run the above `removeClass` and `addClass` method manually on firebug and see if it's working. If working then problem is in your if...else condition.

Comment: put your is_page() function here in the question....

Comment: @C-linkNepal The code works fine. I have tested it with a change of picture for example

Comment: @Utkanos there is no HTML. I amjust trying to change a css class for a specific page.

Comment: @WouterFlorijn Yes they are executed. I have tested it.

Comment: @ohlec I am getting a blank white page

Comment: I don't understand. If there's no HTML, what are you trying to change CSS on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing seems to be correct. You need to make sure your is_page function does whatever it does correctly, and that your css class manipulation only runs once the document object is ready.
You have not tagged this post as a jquery post, but since you are using jquery in your example i will also use jquery.

Live demo:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/ne842udn/

use

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

to ensure that your document is ready to manipulate.

and have some identifier somewhere to tell your script which page you are on (i use a hidden field in my example) like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="pageId" value="970" />
```

and a page identifier like:

```
function is_page(num){
    return $('input[name="pageId"][value="' + num + '"]').length > 0;
}
```

Solves your problem? Solves everything i could read that you were asking about ;)
Try changing the value of the input field at the top of the HTML section of the fiddle to something else you have a style set for, like 877, then hit run at the top left corner on the page and watch the background of the div change color.

You could just have your server-side php code set the class directly though, would work for users who have javascript disabled **(or if you don't care about those users, think about what really needs to be run client side vs serverside.. clientside scripts should add interaction or something, not just help a lazy programmer style is pages)**

Comment: Thanks for answering!
what I want is that whenever a certain page is loaded, a certain css class changes so it is compatible with the page preferences. From your answer, i can't see how that helps me.. :/

Comment: Lets make sure we talk the same web-dev langauge. What i mean is this: Load a page = Request from browser to your webserver, webserver responds with a page (it is thus loaded). When you load your page from your server, you have specified something that will let your clientside code know what page you are browsing (In my example, i use a hidden field supplied from the server for this, you could use a querystring, data-attribute or whatever). And i also read your page preference as something defined on/by your server, NOT an option a user have selected (such as switching a theme).

Comment: Now please  explain what/how you want it to work :) (Also, did you check the demo i posted? You will have to simulate loading different pages by changing the value in the <input> and clicking the Run button)

Comment: I found it. Based on your code, I did this:


<?php
  if ( is_page(877) ) { ?>
  <aside id="header-aside" class=" header-two-aside2 clr">
  <?php }  
   else { ?>
    <aside id="header-aside" class=" header-two-aside clr">
   <?php } ?>

Comment: Ah, but then its not javascript at all, the <?php SOME CODE HERE ?> means that its serverside code, once your webpage is rendered on your server and sent to your clients browser the code inside the <? ?> have already been executed. But i am happy to hear that you solved it.